# Get timeline entry and template used for active complication?

Tags: swift, swift2, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'd like to conditionally reload my active complication in the `requestedUpdateDidBegin` function or actually tell `ClockKit` to set the next check 15 minutes before the end of the current timeline entry, but how can I do that without knowing what's in the current complication?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
    if let complications = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance().activeComplications {
        for item in complications {
            // Get timeline entry and template used?
        }
    }
```

For the current complication, I can only get the family, but no other info like timeline date or template used. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: I'm trying to refresh the ring for the current complication. So actually I'd like to get the current timeline entry and refresh it 15 mins before it expires. Otherwise, the ring gets stale pretty quick and can only refresh it about every 30 mins. It would be nice if I can populate the fill fraction with a relative date for example. My complication is almost like a timer displayed as a ring.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no relative fill fraction support.  [Feature request it.](https://bugreport.apple.com/) But if you're only providing `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication` you could (use the minimum 10-minute scheduled update interval to keep it somewhat fresh, or) schedule the update as explained in the answer by offsetting the current entry's date.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and approach, current timeline function will work as you mention. I filled a feature request in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The complication server](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/CLKComplicationServer_class/index.html) requests data from your complication controller, but it's not designed to provide its timeline data to you. All you can find out from the server are the earliest and latest time travel dates.

You'd have to get timeline details from the original data you used to create the timeline entries in the first place.

As for scheduling your update 15 minutes before the end of the last entry, you can very easily schedule that as part of the *previous* reload request. The very last thing the complication server requests (after reloading or extending the timeline) is the next update date.

Since the complication server has just asked you for the future timeline entries in `getTimelineEntriesForComplication:afterDate:`, you can make note of the last timeline entry's date, offset it by 15 minutes, then return that new date once `getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler` momentarily gets called.